# What is the difference between if: ${{ condition }} and if: condition?

Tags: github-actions

I have this GitHub Actions workflow in which have this condition based on which step is getting executed.

if `inputs.skip_test == true`, the test execution will be skipped and should run only if previous `inputs.skip_test == false` and previous step is `success`

This block did execute even the `inputs.skip_test == false` coming from choice parameter.

```
name: execute tests
if: ${{ inputs.skip_test == true }} && success()
run: mvn test
```

When I changed to below (removed `${{ }}`) it run correctly as expected.

```
name: execute tests
if: inputs.skip_test == true && success()
run: mvn test
```

Comment: [_"When you use expressions in an `if` conditional, you can, optionally, omit the `${{ }}` expression syntax..."_](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#jobsjob_idstepsif) (unless the expression starts with `!`, as that is reserved in YAML).

Comment: Pretty sure `$ {{` (with a blank) is incorrect syntax, though.

Comment: Yeah sry, It was typo in question, it is correct in code. GitHub workflow throws error if there's space as you said `$ {{`